# Microsoft Excel 2010 Copy/Paste Edit Ideas & Help Request On Minor Detail

Tags: excel, vba

Yes, I have written this Macro for Microsoft Excel (2010 if that helps), with the assistance of someone else. I am wondering if anyone has a way of shortening it, and making it more efficient. However still getting the same outcome it gave before? An example of the CSV format I have to work with can be found here... And yes, unfortunately, they do have to be put into those columns and cells..

The only issue I am really stumped on is this:
on `.Cell(2, 3)` for example... If you notice, on each section it would copy and paste, it has a new row.. I want it to do that.. I am novice at this, and could not find a way to make it just paste each one to the next available row.. So my solution for this was to do 2, 3, 4, 5.. And so on.. If anyone knows how to change this as well to make this.. Loop? Per say, that would be great help. Just loop for the amount of data that is being copied though, and not repeat.

Here is an example CSV: [Media Fire](http://www.mediafire.com/?x5fg4ln4568h7pz) It's Clean, I promise. Thank you for your time.

Macro Code to copy certain Column/Row data Cells from one sheet to another to specific Cells

```
Sub FormatData()
Dim col As Integer

For col = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(2, 2) = Cells(1, col)
       .Cells(2, 3) = Cells(2, col) & ". " & Cells(3, col) & ". " & Cells(4, col) & ". " & Cells(5, col) & "."
       .Cells(2, 4) = Cells(7, col)
       .Cells(2, 5) = Cells(10, col)
    End With
Next col
    For col = 2 To 2
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(3, 2) = Cells(1, col)
       .Cells(3, 3) = Cells(2, col) & ". " & Cells(3, col) & ". " & Cells(4, col) & ". " & Cells(5, col) & "."
       .Cells(3, 4) = Cells(7, col)
       .Cells(3, 5) = Cells(10, col)
    End With
Next col
    For col = 3 To 3
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(4, 2) = Cells(1, col)
       .Cells(4, 3) = Cells(2, col) & ". " & Cells(3, col) & ". " & Cells(4, col) & ". " & Cells(5, col) & "."
       .Cells(4, 4) = Cells(7, col)
       .Cells(4, 5) = Cells(10, col)
    End With
Next col
    For col = 4 To 4
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(5, 2) = Cells(1, col)
       .Cells(5, 3) = Cells(2, col) & ". " & Cells(3, col) & ". " & Cells(4, col) & ". " & Cells(5, col) & "."
       .Cells(5, 4) = Cells(7, col)
       .Cells(5, 5) = Cells(10, col)
    End With
Next col

    For col = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(6, 2) = Cells(13, col)
       .Cells(6, 3) = Cells(14, col) & ". " & Cells(15, col) & ". " & Cells(16, col) & ". " & Cells(17, col) & "."
       .Cells(6, 4) = Cells(19, col)
       .Cells(6, 5) = Cells(22, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 2 To 2
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(7, 2) = Cells(13, col)
       .Cells(7, 3) = Cells(14, col) & ". " & Cells(15, col) & ". " & Cells(16, col) & ". " & Cells(17, col) & "."
       .Cells(7, 4) = Cells(19, col)
       .Cells(7, 5) = Cells(22, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 3 To 3
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(8, 2) = Cells(13, col)
       .Cells(8, 3) = Cells(14, col) & ". " & Cells(15, col) & ". " & Cells(16, col) & ". " & Cells(17, col) & "."
       .Cells(8, 4) = Cells(19, col)
       .Cells(8, 5) = Cells(22, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 4 To 4
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(9, 2) = Cells(13, col)
       .Cells(9, 3) = Cells(14, col) & ". " & Cells(15, col) & ". " & Cells(16, col) & ". " & Cells(17, col) & "."
       .Cells(9, 4) = Cells(19, col)
       .Cells(9, 5) = Cells(22, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(10, 2) = Cells(25, col)
       .Cells(10, 3) = Cells(26, col) & ". " & Cells(27, col) & ". " & Cells(28, col) & ". " & Cells(29, col) & "."
       .Cells(10, 4) = Cells(31, col)
       .Cells(10, 5) = Cells(34, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 2 To 2
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(11, 2) = Cells(25, col)
       .Cells(11, 3) = Cells(26, col) & ". " & Cells(27, col) & ". " & Cells(28, col) & ". " & Cells(29, col) & "."
       .Cells(11, 4) = Cells(31, col)
       .Cells(11, 5) = Cells(34, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 3 To 3
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(12, 2) = Cells(25, col)
       .Cells(12, 3) = Cells(26, col) & ". " & Cells(27, col) & ". " & Cells(28, col) & ". " & Cells(29, col) & "."
       .Cells(12, 4) = Cells(31, col)
       .Cells(12, 5) = Cells(34, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 4 To 4
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(13, 2) = Cells(25, col)
       .Cells(13, 3) = Cells(26, col) & ". " & Cells(27, col) & ". " & Cells(28, col) & ". " & Cells(29, col) & "."
       .Cells(13, 4) = Cells(31, col)
       .Cells(13, 5) = Cells(34, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(14, 2) = Cells(37, col)
       .Cells(14, 3) = Cells(38, col) & ". " & Cells(39, col) & ". " & Cells(40, col) & ". " & Cells(41, col) & "."
       .Cells(14, 4) = Cells(43, col)
       .Cells(14, 5) = Cells(46, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 2 To 2
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(15, 2) = Cells(37, col)
       .Cells(15, 3) = Cells(38, col) & ". " & Cells(39, col) & ". " & Cells(40, col) & ". " & Cells(41, col) & "."
       .Cells(15, 4) = Cells(43, col)
       .Cells(15, 5) = Cells(46, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 3 To 3
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(16, 2) = Cells(37, col)
       .Cells(16, 3) = Cells(38, col) & ". " & Cells(39, col) & ". " & Cells(40, col) & ". " & Cells(41, col) & "."
       .Cells(16, 4) = Cells(43, col)
       .Cells(16, 5) = Cells(46, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 4 To 4
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(17, 2) = Cells(37, col)
       .Cells(17, 3) = Cells(38, col) & ". " & Cells(39, col) & ". " & Cells(40, col) & ". " & Cells(41, col) & "."
       .Cells(17, 4) = Cells(43, col)
       .Cells(17, 5) = Cells(46, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(18, 2) = Cells(49, col)
       .Cells(18, 3) = Cells(50, col) & ". " & Cells(51, col) & ". " & Cells(52, col) & ". " & Cells(53, col) & "."
       .Cells(18, 4) = Cells(55, col)
       .Cells(18, 5) = Cells(58, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 2 To 2
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(19, 2) = Cells(49, col)
       .Cells(19, 3) = Cells(50, col) & ". " & Cells(51, col) & ". " & Cells(52, col) & ". " & Cells(53, col) & "."
       .Cells(19, 4) = Cells(55, col)
       .Cells(19, 5) = Cells(58, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 3 To 3
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(20, 2) = Cells(49, col)
       .Cells(20, 3) = Cells(50, col) & ". " & Cells(51, col) & ". " & Cells(52, col) & ". " & Cells(53, col) & "."
       .Cells(20, 4) = Cells(55, col)
       .Cells(20, 5) = Cells(58, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 4 To 4
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(21, 2) = Cells(49, col)
       .Cells(21, 3) = Cells(50, col) & ". " & Cells(51, col) & ". " & Cells(52, col) & ". " & Cells(53, col) & "."
       .Cells(21, 4) = Cells(55, col)
       .Cells(21, 5) = Cells(58, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(22, 2) = Cells(61, col)
       .Cells(22, 3) = Cells(62, col) & ". " & Cells(63, col) & ". " & Cells(64, col) & ". " & Cells(65, col) & "."
       .Cells(22, 4) = Cells(67, col)
       .Cells(22, 5) = Cells(70, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 2 To 2
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(23, 2) = Cells(61, col)
       .Cells(23, 3) = Cells(62, col) & ". " & Cells(63, col) & ". " & Cells(64, col) & ". " & Cells(65, col) & "."
       .Cells(23, 4) = Cells(67, col)
       .Cells(23, 5) = Cells(70, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 3 To 3
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(24, 2) = Cells(61, col)
       .Cells(24, 3) = Cells(62, col) & ". " & Cells(63, col) & ". " & Cells(64, col) & ". " & Cells(65, col) & "."
       .Cells(24, 4) = Cells(67, col)
       .Cells(24, 5) = Cells(70, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 4 To 4
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(25, 2) = Cells(61, col)
       .Cells(25, 3) = Cells(62, col) & ". " & Cells(63, col) & ". " & Cells(64, col) & ". " & Cells(65, col) & "."
       .Cells(25, 4) = Cells(67, col)
       .Cells(25, 5) = Cells(70, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(26, 2) = Cells(73, col)
       .Cells(26, 3) = Cells(74, col) & ". " & Cells(75, col) & ". " & Cells(76, col) & ". " & Cells(77, col) & "."
       .Cells(26, 4) = Cells(79, col)
       .Cells(26, 5) = Cells(82, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 2 To 2
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(27, 2) = Cells(73, col)
       .Cells(27, 3) = Cells(74, col) & ". " & Cells(75, col) & ". " & Cells(76, col) & ". " & Cells(77, col) & "."
       .Cells(27, 4) = Cells(79, col)
       .Cells(27, 5) = Cells(82, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 3 To 3
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(28, 2) = Cells(73, col)
       .Cells(28, 3) = Cells(74, col) & ". " & Cells(75, col) & ". " & Cells(76, col) & ". " & Cells(77, col) & "."
       .Cells(28, 4) = Cells(79, col)
       .Cells(28, 5) = Cells(82, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 4 To 4
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(29, 2) = Cells(73, col)
       .Cells(29, 3) = Cells(74, col) & ". " & Cells(75, col) & ". " & Cells(76, col) & ". " & Cells(77, col) & "."
       .Cells(29, 4) = Cells(79, col)
       .Cells(29, 5) = Cells(82, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(30, 2) = Cells(85, col)
       .Cells(30, 3) = Cells(86, col) & ". " & Cells(87, col) & ". " & Cells(88, col) & ". " & Cells(89, col) & "."
       .Cells(30, 4) = Cells(91, col)
       .Cells(30, 5) = Cells(94, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 2 To 2
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(31, 2) = Cells(85, col)
       .Cells(31, 3) = Cells(86, col) & ". " & Cells(87, col) & ". " & Cells(88, col) & ". " & Cells(89, col) & "."
       .Cells(31, 4) = Cells(91, col)
       .Cells(31, 5) = Cells(94, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 3 To 3
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(32, 2) = Cells(85, col)
       .Cells(32, 3) = Cells(86, col) & ". " & Cells(87, col) & ". " & Cells(88, col) & ". " & Cells(89, col) & "."
       .Cells(32, 4) = Cells(91, col)
       .Cells(32, 5) = Cells(94, col)
    End With
Next col
        For col = 4 To 4
    With Worksheets(2)
       .Cells(33, 2) = Cells(85, col)
       .Cells(33, 3) = Cells(86, col) & ". " & Cells(87, col) & ". " & Cells(88, col) & ". " & Cells(89, col) & "."
       .Cells(33, 4) = Cells(91, col)
       .Cells(33, 5) = Cells(94, col)
    End With
Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: ok, updated the answer, works great with your data now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a refactored `Sub`

Points to note:

- use variant arrays for the looping/data processing because looping through cells is slow
- you can change the value of `srcBlocks` to control how many blocks to process, or extract it from your source data
- refering to the destination sheet by index can be problematic if it is moved.  Safer to refer to it by name  `Worksheets("SheetName")`

.

```
Sub FormatData()
    Dim rw2 As Integer, rwA As Integer, colA As Integer
    Dim vDst() As Variant, vSrc As Variant
    Dim srcBlocks As Integer

    srcBlocks = 8 ' process 8 blocks of 12 rows

    vSrc = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D" & srcBlocks * 12)
    ReDim vDst(1 To srcBlocks * 4 + 1, 1 To 5)

    For rwA = 0 To srcBlocks * 12 - 1 Step 12  ' = 0, 12, 24, ...
        For colA = 1 To 4                      ' 4 columns in Src
            rw2 = (rwA \ 12) * 4 + colA + 1    ' 4 Dst rws per block, = 2..5, 6..9, ...

            vDst(rw2, 2) = vSrc(rwA + 1, colA)
            vDst(rw2, 3) = vSrc(rwA + 2, colA) & ". " & _
                           vSrc(rwA + 3, colA) & ". " & _
                           vSrc(rwA + 4, colA) & ". " & _
                           vSrc(rwA + 5, colA) & "."
            vDst(rw2, 4) = vSrc(rwA + 7, colA)
            vDst(rw2, 5) = vSrc(rwA + 10, colA)
        Next colA
    Next rwA

    Worksheets(2).Range("A1:E" & CStr(srcBlocks * 4 + 1)) = vDst
End Sub
```

To add flexability, for variable number of columns in Source data

```
Sub FormatData()
    Dim rw2 As Integer, rwA As Integer, colA As Integer
    Dim vDst() As Variant, vSrc As Variant
    Dim srcBlocks As Integer, srcColumns As Integer

    srcBlocks = 8  ' process 8 blocks of 12 rows '
    srcColumns = 5 ' Columns in source data '

    vSrc = ActiveSheet.Range( _
             ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
             ActiveSheet.Cells(srcBlocks * 12, srcColumns))
    ReDim vDst(1 To srcBlocks * srcColumns + 1, 1 To 5)

    For rwA = 0 To srcBlocks * 12 - 1 Step 12           ' = 0, 12, 24, ... '
        For colA = 1 To srcColumns                      ' srcColumns columns in Source '
            rw2 = (rwA \ 12) * srcColumns + colA + 1    ' srcColumns rows in Destination per Source block '

            vDst(rw2, 2) = vSrc(rwA + 1, colA)
            vDst(rw2, 3) = vSrc(rwA + 2, colA) & ". " & _
                         vSrc(rwA + 3, colA) & ". " & _
                         vSrc(rwA + 4, colA) & ". " & _
                         vSrc(rwA + 5, colA) & "."
            vDst(rw2, 4) = vSrc(rwA + 7, colA)
            vDst(rw2, 5) = vSrc(rwA + 10, colA)
        Next colA
    Next rwA

    Worksheets(2).Range("A1:E" & CStr(srcBlocks * 4 + 1)) = vDst
End Sub
```

Comment: If I needed to change the amount of rows it were to copy to sheet two, to make sure I don't mess it up.. How would I go about doing that? Other than that, Works great! Thank you!

(I think you mean the srcBlocks is that though, correct?)

Comment: @Leaum, updated answer to allow for variable number of columns.  I'm not sure what you are asking about srcBlocks ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty compact way of doing it, note that the slash in the rindex formula is a backslash:

```
Sub FormatData()

Dim rw As Integer
Dim rindex As Integer

  With Worksheets(2)
      For rw = 2 To 33
          rindex = (rw - 2) \ 4
          .Cells(rw, 2) = Cells(12 * rindex + 1, (rw - 1) - 4 * rindex)
          .Cells(rw, 3) = Cells(12 * rindex + 2, (rw - 1) - 4 * rindex) & "." & _
                          Cells(12 * rindex + 3, (rw - 1) - 4 * rindex) & "." & _
                          Cells(12 * rindex + 4, (rw - 1) - 4 * rindex) & "." & _
                          Cells(12 * rindex + 5, (rw - 1) - 4 * rindex) & "."
          .Cells(rw, 4) = Cells(12 * rindex + 7, (rw - 1) - 4 * rindex)
          .Cells(rw, 5) = Cells(12 * rindex + 10, (rw - 1) - 4 * rindex)
      Next rw
  End With

End Sub
```